# grep a list of specific files

Tags: grep

I need to grep for a string but only within certain files within a directory- eg:

> grep -rl mystring "file1.txt file2.txt file3.blah"

what is the correct syntax?  I am working in a Linux OS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Drop the quotes around the file names so that they are treated as separate parameters. Also, I don't think you need the -r since you are just specifying files and not folders.

```
grep  mystring file1.txt file2.txt file3.blah
```

You might want to check out http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html (or man grep) for other examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give the list without quotes, it will list all results with the file they are in. eg:

```
grep init foo.py bar.py
foo.py:    def __init__(self, label, active, filter, filter_string):
foo.py:    def __init__(self):
bar.py:    def __init__(self, prefs, num_panes):
```